# Formato de solicitud no reconocido para la dirección URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, iis

Al realizar una petición con `ajax` a un servicio `soap` (envío de archivos) devuelve un error 500 (Error interno de servidor). Lo que me causa ruido es que al probar la función de manera local en el servidor funciona todo bien, pero al usarla mediante la dirección publicada no funciona y solo me pasa con el envío de archivos ya que al realizar una consulta del directorio en donde deberían guardarse no genera error. data es un `FormData()` en donde van los archivos seleccionados.

función `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/servicioSoap.asmx/cargaArchivo?Categoria=" + $(".clsCategoria:checked").val(),
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 60000,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
            $("#loader").removeClass('oculta-paso-uno');
        },
        success: function (resultado) {
            $("#loader").addClass('oculta-paso-uno');
            var respuesta = JSON.parse($(resultado).find('string').text());
            if ((!respuesta.exito) && respuesta.redireccion != "") {
                window.location = resultado.redireccion;
            }
            fn_mostrarMensaje(1, respuesta.resultado);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#loader").addClass('oculta-paso-uno');
            var error = "Ocurrió un eeror, intenta mas tarde.\n" + errorThrown;
            fn_mostrarMensaje(1, error);
        }
    });
```

El log de IIS me arroja:

> Exception information: Exception type: InvalidOperationException
>   Exception message: Formato de solicitud no reconocido para la
>   dirección URL, finaliza de manera inesperada en '/cargaArchivo'. en
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type
>   type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
>   etc...

Comment: el Error 500 es error en el backend no en tu AJAX deberias de ver el log de tu back

Comment: Estimado, coloca el log del error en el backend y el código al cual llama ese ajax para poder orientarte

Comment: Disculpen mi ignorancia. ¿En donde puedo ver los logs que me comentan? Tengo acceso al servidor IIS pero no se en donde puedo ver los logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buscando en erroes con base en ***Formato de solicitud no reconocido para la dirección URL  finaliza de manera inesperada en `/cargaArchivo`***
pude ver que me hacia falta en el `web.config` lo siguiente dentro de `<system.web>`.

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: Buenisimo que encontraste el problema. Trata de hacer un poco mas clara la pregunta (ya que como esta, deberiamos cerrarla como no reproducible) y recuerda aceptar tu respuesta pasadas las 24 hs!

Comment: recuerda aceptar tu respuesta! en 24 Horas puedes ayudar a otras personas y recibir +1 por tu respuesta